# Adding COMPRESSION_DELAY to an existing COLUMNSTORE INDEX

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, columnstore

When I create an COLUMNSTORE index I can specify `COMPRESSION_DELAY = x [minutes]` in the CREATE-Statement. It delays the movement of the rows in an closed segment from the delta store to the compressed columnstore storage. Reason to do so: your import process is not just a simple INSERT but has some UPDATEs and maybe DELETEs too.

Is there a way to set this value afterwards without recreating the whole index (which would take very long on our big table)?

I tested already REBUILD and REORGANIZE, but they both do not understand the `COMPRESSION_DELAY` option in the `WITH()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An existing columnstore index can be altered as such:

```
ALTER INDEX ColumnstoreIndexName ON SchemaName.ObjectName
SET (COMPRESSION_DELAY  = x Minutes);
```

As found in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on `ALTER INDEX`

```
ALTER INDEX { index_name | ALL } ON <object>  
{  
...
    | SET ( <set_index_option> [ ,...n ] ) 


<set_index_option>::=  
{  
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = { ON | OFF }  
    | ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = { ON | OFF }  
    | OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = { ON | OFF}
    | IGNORE_DUP_KEY = { ON | OFF }  
    | STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = { ON | OFF }  
    | COMPRESSION_DELAY= {0 | delay [Minutes]}  
}
```

Comment: I submitted a PR on the docs to have this option removed from the ALTER INDEX REBUILD section.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft is it a typo in the documentation?

Comment: It was in the wrong place.  COMPTESSION_DELAY does not belong in `<rebuild_index_option>`.  Docs are correct now.  See https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/commit/3d87ab4da209cb1ba8990167fc7ab8c66532a0ea?short_path=39c9e3c#diff-39c9e3c739fbf6ebc715d9369e54b4c6cdc9b6d9e9f3079498e826c6e742b681